# Link in custom area inside svg image does not work

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to create some links and hover effects inside a svg image. So, I created some custom transparent areas inside one svg image, in an online images editor, in order to do that. But when I try to apply some links in those custom areas, as show below, it does not work. How can I make it work?

```
<body>
  <svg>
      <defs></defs>
      <!-- custom ellipse which the link does not work -->
      <a href="some-link.com">
          <ellipse />  
      </a>

      <!-- normal path from the svg image, which the link work -->
      <a href="some-link.com">
          <path></path>
      </a>

      <!--rest of the image with many paths-->
      <path></path>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe one of the many other paths are overlapping the ellipse

Comment: Maybe, but in the svg the ellipse comes before the paths, as in the example above. You know how can I make the ellipse overlap the other paths?

Comment: @Marcelo From the code it looks correct - the problem must be somewhere else. Could you please provide us with some demo or snippet, so we can replicate the issue?

Comment: You can add pointer-events="none" for the overlapping paths. Alternatively you can use javascript and append the <a> at the end of the document with svg.appendChild(theA);

Answer (score 0):

The `ellipse` element seems to be invalid. And since the markup has an error, it might affect even the functionality of the parent element.

The self-closing tag should have the slash at the end (since SVG is based on more strict XML) like below:

```
<ellipse />
```

Does this change solve the problem with the link?

Comment: Yes sure, thanks. I've just fixed that. But this is just an example structure of the actual svg image. And I didn't change the svg file, just added the a tag and some classes to check

Comment: @Marcelo Great! So would you please be so nice and add the answer to this page, so the others with similar issue can learn from it?

Comment: Sure Tomas! Hope to find some workaround soon

Comment: @Marcelo Ah, my bad. I thought you have already fixed the whole issue.

Answer (score 0):

CSS can be used to override the default cursor style in SVG. This helped in my case.

```
svg {
  cursor: default;
}

svg a {
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```